# Reading Checkbox status from another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

Am trying to read the value of a checkbox from a BackgroundWorker in WPF:

This doesn't work:

```
bool? isSleepChecked = checkBoxSleep.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (ThreadStart)delegate{ return checkBoxSleep.IsChecked;});
```

Cannot convert anonymous method to delegate type 'System.Threading.ThreadStart' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

EDIT - Here is HB's answer expressed using a delegate instead of lambda which I find slightly more readable

```
bool? isSleepChecked = (bool?)checkBoxSleep.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Func<bool?>(delegate { return checkBoxSleep.IsChecked; }));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assign the variable instead, then you don't need a `return`.

```
bool? isSleepChecked;
checkBoxSleep.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(
    () => isSleepChecked = checkBoxSleep.IsChecked));
```

Alternatively you can use a delegate with return value (e.g. a [`Func<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx)):

```
bool? isSleepChecked = checkBoxSleep.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Func<bool?>(
                            () => checkBoxSleep.IsChecked));
```

*(Requires return type cast before .NET 4.5)*

Comment: Thanks HB (and Douglas too).  Very similar answers. I seem to prefer the Func answer.. and there is a typo.. should be: new Func<bool?>

Comment: @DaveMateer: Was just about to fix that :)

Comment: Cheers - put in the delegate version above.

Comment: @DaveMateer: Lambdas are awesome, spare you two keywords (and they have an arrow!). But each their own i suppose...

Answer (score 2):

Your code will not compile because, whilst you are attempting to return a `bool?` from your delegate, `ThreadStart` has a return type of `void`.

The easiest approach in such cases would probably be to capture your `isSleepChecked` variable within a lambda expression and set it directly:

```
bool? isSleepChecked = null;
checkBoxSleep.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{ 
    isSleepChecked = checkBoxSleep.IsChecked; 
}), 
    DispatcherPriority.Normal);
```