# Reading Checkbox status from other thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

Basically it's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266908/reading-checkbox-status-from-another-thread) question but then for VB.net. I need to check the `CheckBox` state from another thread than the main thread. Solutions for the linked question contain C# code. On-line translators do not yield understandable results.

My code (stripped down to the essential parts):

```
Public Class UI
    'UI contains CheckBox1.
End Class

Public Class Worker
    Public Sub Input()
        Dim thrMyThread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Run)
        thrMyThread.Start()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Run()
        If UI.CheckBox1.Checked = True
            MsgBox("True")
            ShellandWait("application.exe")
        Else
            MsgBox("False")
            ShellandWait("application.exe")
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

`ShellandWait` is a custom function which starts a process and waits until it exits.
Because of the `ShellandWait` I need another thread to keep my UI responsive.

**UPDATE**
I did find a work around by defining a `Public` boolean variable at the beginning of the Worker Class, which represents the state of the `UI.CheckBox`. So:

```
Public Class Worker
    Public cB As Boolean = UI.CheckBox.Checked
    ... 'Rest of Code
    Public Sub Run()
        If cB = True
            MsgBox("True")
            ShellandWait("application.exe")
        Else
            MsgBox("False")
            ShellandWait("application.exe")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: But if, after the ShellandWait, you need to use again the cB var, it could be no more correct. (if your user clicks again on the textbox while your thread is waiting)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm aware that this is a sloppy work-around. Because I have simplified my code shown here I left some parts out. The methods in the Worker Class are triggered by a "Go" button in the UI. It makes no sense for the user to change controls in the UI while the application is running. If he wants to change a control, the user stops the application with a stop button (kills the .exe process), adjust a control (say, the CheckBox) and then clicks the "Go" button again.

Comment: The most important thing you left out is that UI is a class derived from Form.  Which is the only way you can possibly be using a *type* as though it is an object.  And also the reason the code didn't work.  On another thread, UI is suddenly a different object.  Don't write code like this, it fatally destroys your odds of ever understanding OOP.  And getting threading right.

Comment: @HansPassant Could you maybe elaborate on "And also the reason the code didn't work"? I am a beginner in VB and this set-up seemed logical to me. What is the proper way of doing such a code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force multi-threaded VB.NET class to display results on a single form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273639/force-multi-threaded-vb-net-class-to-display-results-on-a-single-form)

Comment: The proper way is to use an object and not a type.  Consider learning C# first, it will force you to understand the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. This code will enable you to access the GUI from worker-threads.

```
Public Delegate Function GetCheckBoxChekedDelegate(cb As CheckBox) As Boolean

Public Function GetCheckBoxChekedFunction(cb As CheckBox) As Boolean
    Return cb.Checked
End Function

Public Function GetChecked(cb As CheckBox) As Boolean
    If cb.InvokeRequired Then

        Dim del As GetCheckBoxChekedDelegate
        del = AddressOf GetCheckBoxChekedFunction


        Dim parArray() As Object = {cb}

        Return CBool(cb.Invoke(del, parArray))
        'Return CBool(cb.Invoke(del, New Object() {cb}))
        'Return CBool(cb.Invoke(del, {cb}))

    Else
        Return cb.Checked

    End If
End Function
```

You can use the *GetChecked* function to get the checked state of the checkbox, the function will works both on the main thread, and on a worker thread.

When the *GetChecked* function is called from a worker thread the *InvokeRequired* will return true, so the *cb.Checked* value is read in the function *GetCheckBoxChekedFunction* which **is called on the main thread** by the *cb.Invoke(del, {cb})* command.

Comment: The `Return CBool(cb.Invoke(del, {cb}))` gives an "Expression expected error" during compile time. Error points to the first curly brace `{`

Comment: ehm... "it works on my machines"... I'm using VS 2010 targetting .Net 4, if you copy/paste the code in a form, it should work. But it should work anywhere, I've used it tenth of times from the .Net 1.1 years...

Comment: Where exactly is the error? does VS give you any correction options?

Comment: I'm compiling using option strict ON, option explicit ON, option infer ON

Comment: I'm on Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition, with .Net 3.5. The error points to the first `{` to the left of `cb`. I'm using none of these compiling options.

Comment: sorry, made a mistake. I compile with Explicit and Infer ON

Comment: I've updated the code again, using an explicit definition for the parameters array

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11559/discussion-between-bart-arondson-and-max)